# Mongo DB remove old data using remove command

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

My mongo db contains

```
> db.collection.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f8e493d97731874b1235bd"), "Date" : "14-12-2014", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f8e497d97731874b1235be"), "Date" : "14-11-2014", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f917f748f91b35cf1ddaac"), "Date" : "14-01-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f917fc48f91b35cf1ddaad"), "Date" : "14-02-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180148f91b35cf1ddaae"), "Date" : "14-03-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180848f91b35cf1ddaaf"), "Date" : "14-04-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180f48f91b35cf1ddab0"), "Date" : "14-05-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9181448f91b35cf1ddab1"), "Date" : "14-06-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9181948f91b35cf1ddab2"), "Date" : "14-07-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9181d48f91b35cf1ddab3"), "Date" : "14-08-2015", "Value" : 25.36 }
```

I want to delete three months old data. For that

```
> db.collection.remove( { "Date": {$lt:"14-10-2014"} } );
```

I tried like this but it's not working properly. It's deleting depending only on month e.g. it's deleting from today to jan 2105 and ninth month of 2014 to jan 2104 but not December & November of 2104. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your problem is that MongoDB doesn't see your Date field as a date but a string. They need to be ISODate()'s for the $lt operator to work. Change the dates and your query will work.

Comment: Why do you post this not as an answer? It helps other people to see that there is already a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try the below code. You can remove the docs without updating the Date field to [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/shell-types/). As a good practice, you should always store date as an [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/shell-types/). It makes querying easy.

```
var cursor = db.collection.find()
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
 var doc = cursor.next();
 var docDate = doc.Date;
 var queryDate = "14-10-2014";
 var docDateMillis = new Date(docDate.substring(6,10), docDate.substring(3,5)-1, docDate.substring(0,2)).getTime();
 var queryDateMillis = new Date(queryDate.substring(6,10), queryDate.substring(3,5)-1, queryDate.substring(0,2)).getTime()
 if(docDateMillis < queryDateMillis) {
   db.collection.remove({_id : doc._id})
 }     
}
```

Comment: Sure you can do it without preliminary "update" but I will not go for this even if it remove document because OP will likely want to do execute other queries operations on Date field and the solution using update will be faster. Also as you said date should an ISO

Comment: @user3100115: I totally agree with you

Comment: Thanks Rudra. Ya its working good. But how can i pass this function to DB using perl

Answer (score 1):

Your Date field is not valid so first you need to update your documents. The best way is using the ["Bulk()"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    count = 0

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var newDate = new Date(doc.Date.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$2-$1")); 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "Date": newDate }});
    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if (count % 100 != 0)
    bulk.execute();
```

---

Your documents now look like this:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f8e493d97731874b1235bd"), "Date" : ISODate("2014-12-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f8e497d97731874b1235be"), "Date" : ISODate("2014-11-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f917f748f91b35cf1ddaac"), "Date" : ISODate("2015-01-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f917fc48f91b35cf1ddaad"), "Date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180148f91b35cf1ddaae"), "Date" : ISODate("2015-03-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180848f91b35cf1ddaaf"), "Date" : ISODate("2015-04-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f9180f48f91b35cf1ddab0"), "Date" : ISODate("2015-05-13T21:00:00Z"), "Value" : 25.36 }
```

---

Then you can use the `.remove` method to remove old document.

```js
db.collection.remove({ "Date": { "$lt": new Date("10-14-2014")} }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job

```
    db.test.remove({'$where':function(){ 
        var x = this.Date.split('-');
        var dt = new Date(x[2], x[1] - 1, x[0]);
        var y='14-10-2014'.split('-');
        var chkDt = new Date(y[2], y[1] - 1, y[0]);
        return dt < chkDt; }})
```

Although it would be better if you use ISODate() in the document while storing