# MongoDB String to Date?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

Following is the JSON of the data:

```
{
  projectName: String,
  projectDescription: String,
  users: [

  ],
  projectManager: [

  ],
  teamLead: [

  ],
  createdBy: String,
  superAdmin: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  task: [
    {
      userID: String,
      name: String,
      taskName: String,
      nohrs: Number,
      description: String,
      comments: String,
      date: String,
      from: String,
      to: String,
      lastUpdatedDate: String
    }
  ]
}
```

The array of task contains many tasks for each project. And each task has a date in string format. I need to convert each string date to ISO date format.
How can we achieve this?
I have tried this :

```
db.projects.find({}).forEach(function(task){
    task.date = new Date(task.date);
    db.collection.save(task);})
```

but this is adding a column date and not editing the date in task array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo DB remove old data using remove command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602220/mongo-db-remove-old-data-using-remove-command)

Comment: How your dates look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close to the solution. The correct code snippet would be:

```
db.projects.find({}).forEach(function(project){
  project.task.forEach(function(task){
    task.date = new Date(task.date);
  });
  db.projects.save(project);
})
```

You needed one more loop in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     db.projects.find({},function(err,data){
    //this find query will return the array of documents through which we need to iterate

    for(var i =0; i<data.length;i++){

        //then we want convert the date string into Date we need to iterate task array with in each document.

         for(var j = 0;j<data[i].task.length;j++){
           data[i].task[j].date = new Date(data[i].task[j].date);

      }

    }
       //now save the new data 
     data.save();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well guys this worked

```
db.projects.find({}).forEach(function(project){
project.task.forEach(function(task){
 // printjson(task)  
task.date = new Date(task.date);
    print(task.date)
db.projects.save(project);
    })})
```